# Configuring htaccess to read only index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Is their a way I can configure .htaccess file to read only specific files? Say only index.php and not others?

**EDIT:** I know that index.php is the default file that will be read. I want something like this:

If user enters www.example.com it read index.php by default.
If if enters www.example.com/index2.php it is supposed to read index2.php.

Not what I want is to show a 404 error page everywhere whatever the url is. I have only two files are supposed to be read.

Comment: Could you specify what you want to achieve with this? What it's for? You do know that index.php is by default the first page you see when you go to the url of your website?

Comment: The question is vague - what is it you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why a -1? Because you don't have the answer or you didn't get the question?

Comment: I agree, please specify why you downvoted so abhig can do something with that.

Comment: @abhig because your question is unclear and doesn't show any research effort. With .htaccess you can control _access_ to resources, a .htaccess file does not _read_ files. If you want to show a 404 when someone accesses a non-existant resource, you should've said so. Apache will do that by default, so no configuration required here. Also don't forget that other resources (stylesheets, images) are also accessed according to the rules in .htaccess. So please stat what exactly what you want to accomplish, not "how do I do X" when X does not exist.

Comment: I believe the downvote was cast *after* the edit... But in any case, a question is a question. The content matters, not the length. If you deem it to be a bad question, give feedback; it's a nicer gesture.

Answer (score 3):

Zend Framework provides a default .htaccess that routes all requests to index.php, unless the requested file actually exists:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

You may make it more restrictive and route everything to index.php:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Bear in mind that this will make additional requests to, say, CSS files impossible.

[edit]

It's also nice to have a look at the .htaccess provided by Drupal. There, also certain paths and file types are blocked. The very first directive in Drupal's .htaccess is:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$">
    Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>
```

So, if you wanted to block access only to php files and everything in the `application` directory, you would probably do:

```
<FilesMatch "(\.php$|^application)">
    Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>
```

(not tested, as I'm no htaccess expert and the code is just out of my head; if it needs correcting, please someone post a remark in the comments or directly edit my code).

Comment: That's like something I wanted. But I want to allow certain files and stop certain files. Is that possible?

Comment: @abhig See my edited answer. Would this do what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really given much information about what you're really trying to do, If you are trying to require authentication for only certain files then you could use something like the below:

```
<Files "index.php">
require valid-user
</Files>
```

I can't really make any other suggestions without more information, unfortunately.

Comment: I don't get upset; I'm wrong on a daily basis - I'm a developer.